# Make used categories known to @TypeChecked

Tags: groovy, dsl

Is it possible to let the compiler know about the Categories used when executing a closure in groovy?

A small example:

```
class Example {
    static time = evaluateTime {
        println 1.minute.from.now
    }

    static def evaluateTime(Closure<Void> cl) {
        GroovyUtil.use(TimeCategory, cl)
    }
}
```

this works fine when executing, but IntelliJ will gray-out `minute` and if I add the `TypeChecked` Annotation, I get compiler errors.

```
@TypeChecked()
class Example {
    static time = evaluateTime {
        println 1.minute.from.now
    }

    static def evaluateTime(Closure<Void> cl) {
        GroovyUtil.use(TimeCategory, cl)
    }
}
```

In a similar case I found the `DelegatesTo` Annotation to let the compiler know that the closure is executed with a different delegate, but I cannot find a corresponding Annotation for using Categories.

Following [Will P's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37950014/212749) I implemented a small POC extension module.

First I looked at the types involved

- `1` is of type `int`
- `1.minute` is of type `groovy.time.TimeDuration`
- `1.minute.from` is an anonymous class of type `groovy.time.BaseDuration.From`
- `groovy.time.BaseDuration.From` has a `now` property (`getNow` method)

Thus I came up with this Extension

```
class PrecompiledExtension extends GroovyTypeCheckingExtensionSupport.TypeCheckingDSL {
    @Override
    Object run() {
        unresolvedProperty { pexp ->
            if ('minute' == pexp.propertyAsString &&
                    getType(pexp.objectExpression) == classNodeFor(int)) {
                storeType(pexp, classNodeFor(TimeDuration))
                handled = true
            }
            if ('from' == pexp.propertyAsString &&
                    getType(pexp.objectExpression) == classNodeFor(TimeDuration)) {
                storeType(pexp, classNodeFor(BaseDuration.From))
                handled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks at unresolved Properties only.

- If the property name is `minute` and the type of the expression the property is read from is `int`, the result will be of type `TimeDuration`.
- If the property name is `from` and the type of the expression the property is read from is `TimeDuration`, the result will be of type `BaseDuration.From`.

Note that this is just a POC. There is no logic verifying that the missing properties are in a closure that is being called using `TimeCategory`.

To let the compiler use the extension, add the qualified name to the `TypeChecked` Annotation (`type.PrecompiledExtension` in the example below). Note that a class annotated with `TypeChecked` cannot call `GroovyUtil.use`, thus I moved the call to a base class.

```
class ExampleBase {
    static def evaluateTime(@DelegatesTo(TimeCategory) Closure<Void> cl) {
        GroovyUtil.use(TimeCategory, cl)
    }
}

@TypeChecked(extensions = "type.PrecompiledExtension")
class Example extends ExampleBase {

    static time = evaluateTime {
        TimeDuration minute = 1.minute
        BaseDuration.From from = minute.from    

        println 1.minute.from.now
    }
}
```

Note that the `type.PrecompiledExtension` class has to be compiled before the `Example` class. For the POC I disabled `TypeChecked` for a first compile pass and then enabled it again for a second pass.

This works for the compiler, but IntelliJ won't pick this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Categories are not supported by `@TypeChecked`. You can use an [extension module](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_extension_modules) or write your own [type checked extensions](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/type-checking-extensions.html)